# Why does this print 1?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
  int var=0; 
  for(; var++; printf("%d",var)); 
    printf("%d", var); 
}
```

Please explain to me this C code. How is the output 1?

Comment: Ask a specific question. Which *part* of this rather obvious piece of code behaves different from what you expect?

Comment: Check how a for loop behave in your documentation.

Comment: Just read up on how for loop works in C and you will understand how it prints out 1.

Answer (score 2):

You might be confused because of the wrong code indentation. Your code is:

```
for(; var++; printf("%d",var))
    ; 
printf("%d", var);
```

So you always get the output of the second printf. As var is initialized to 0 and `var++` (the for-condition) is always executed, you end up with var==1.

Comment: How you could answer this question even it's closed?

Comment: @Rizier123 [User answering the question after it is closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254819/user-answering-the-question-after-it-is-closed)

Comment: @remyabel ah thank! :D maybe i should google it before i wirte a comment! (I ask because i was wirting an answer too and couldn't send it)